# AWS Vault - Assume another role from within a subshell

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-vault

When using AWS Vault to manage access to AWS accounts form the CLI, is it possible to assume the role specified in profiles for `child1` and/or `child2` while in a subshell for profile  `parent`?

For the profiles in in the example config below, only the account linked to `parent` provides an IAM user (with the key and secret stored in AWS Vault), and that user can assume roles in other accounts. This means that when using the CLI, I must continually switch between `child1` and `child2` (in reality around 12 accounts) when running commands.

For example, if I had the need to list the buckets in each of the child accounts -

```bash
$ aws-vault exec child1
Starting subshell /bin/bash, use `exit` to exit the subshell
$ aws s3 ls > ~/bucket-list/child1.json
$ exit
exit
$
$ aws-vault exec child2
Starting subshell /bin/bash, use `exit` to exit the subshell
$ aws s3 ls > ~/bucket-list/child2.json
$ exit
exit
```

What I'd like to be able to do is start a subshell for the parent account and then switch profile as required, but that doesn't seem to work and instead produces an error. I'm guessing in this scenario that the key and secret for the parent account are required in the config, which would negate the point of AWS Vault.

```bash
$ aws-vault exec parent
Starting subshell /bin/bash, use `exit` to exit the subshell
$aws s3 ls --profile child 1 > ~/bucket-list/child1.json
The source profile "parent" mush have credentials.
```

I realise I could use `aws sts assume-role` to generate some temporary credentials, but that would involve me digging the role ARN out of the config file and then exporting those temporary credentials, which is even more long winded.

Is there a simple way to achieve my goal while in an AWS Vault subshell?

### Example of `~/.aws/config`

```ini
[default]
region = eu-west-2
output = json

[profile parent]
mfa_serial = arn:aws:iam::111111111111:mfa/my-device

[profile child1]
source_profile = parent
include_profile = parent
role_arm = arn:aws:iam::222222222222:role/child1_role

[profile child2]
source_profile = parent
include_profile = parent
role_arm = arn:aws:iam::333333333333:role/child2_role
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per official doc of aws-vault,

> aws-vault uses Amazon's STS service to generate temporary credentials via the GetSessionToken or AssumeRole API calls. These expire in a short period of time, so the risk of leaking credentials is reduced.
>
> AWS Vault then exposes the temporary credentials to the sub-process in one of two ways
>
> - Environment variables are written to the sub-process.
> - Local metadata server
>
> The default is to use environment variables

So once you are using aws-vault, your credentials/keys used in the aws-vault session are stored in the environment variables (you can check this by starting subshell and execute printenv), and overwrite whatever is in the .aws directory.

As said, you can store credentials in your .aws/credentials, but then you lose the whole point of using aws-vault. So I don't think there is a way of doing so. And if you try to nest aws-vault in a subshell, that is prohibited.

[image: nested aws-vault]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Your experience of nesting subshells is the same as mine (forgot to add to question), so no surprise there. It's a shame that this scenario hasn't been considered, as the ability to switch between profiles in such a way would be extremely useful.